# VSCODE extension Remote-Container does not allow me use "workspaceMount"

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to connect to a docker container on a remote host, and I followed the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/develop-remote-host#_converting-an-existing-or-predefined-devcontainerjson by using `devcontainer.json` like:

```json
{
...
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "workspaceMount": "source=/path/to/host/dir,target=/workspace,type=bind,consistency=cached",
...
}
```

but I got an error saying: `Property workspaceMount is not allowed.`

Did some Googling and could not find any site explains this same exact issue.

What is wrong for this? I didn't change any settings of the extension, and I am able to connect to the container and run `bash` shell in it when start terminal after connection.
Its just this `workspaceMount` does not work.